# Properties of stopping time for continuous stochastic process and partial proof verification

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, stochastic-processes, solution-verification

I'm attempting to solve the following problem, am struggling with part (a) and would like to verify my solution for part (b):

[image: s]

---

**My attempt:**

**Part (a):** We have $$E(a(T_r)) = E\left(E\left(\sup_{0 \le s \le T_r} X_s\right)\right) \ge E\left(E\left(\sup_{0 \le s \le T_r} X_s\right) \mathbf{1}(T_r < \infty)\right) \\
= E\left(E\left(X_{T_r}\right) \mathbf{1}(T_r < \infty) \right) = r P(T_r < \infty)$$

where the inequality follows since the $X_t$ are non-negative and the latter two equalities follow since $X_s < r$ on $s < T_r$ and $X_{T_r} = r$ whenever $T_r$ is finite.  Thus it suffices to show that $P(T_r < \infty) \ge 1/2$, although there might be an easier way to approach the problem (or it may be impossible to show this).

**Part (b):** This I can do (I think).  Since $a$ is concave and strictly increasing, $a^{-1}$ is well defined for input on $[0, \infty)$ (not so sure about $\infty$ because I can't prove that $a$ is not bounded yet), increasing and convex.  Thus we may apply Jensen's inequality: $$E(T_r) = E(a^{-1}(a(T_r))) \ge a^{-1}(E(a(T_r)) \ge a^{-1}(1/2)$$ where the last inequality uses the (yet to be proven) part (a).

Comment: What if $\sup_{t\ge 0}X_t\le 1$?

Comment: Maybe the question is poorly specified?  Are there examples for which $a(t)$ is continuous and strictly increasing, $X_t \ge 0$, with your condition holding almost surely? I didn't make it up myself obviously - it's part of a practice exam I found online

Comment: $X_t(\omega)=2\arctan(t)/\pi$.

Comment: Then I suppose there is no way to prove the result asked for. Thank you for this example

Comment: Oh you mean put the indicator in the innermost parentheses? Why is it wrong to do so the way I've set it up?